# Spring Bean Properties file

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, properties, javabeans

Okay, I'm confused here.

I have a properties file with some SQL scripts that I want to store at startup (using Spring MVC servlet container in Tomcat) for later use. Well I think I have the syntax for that down in the *-servlet.xml:

```
<util:properties
  id="findQueries"
  location="classpath:resources/FindQueries.properties" />
```

but I'm not sure how to access it programmatically. I really only need one query from this file in one function of a service-layer class at this point.

I'm fairly new to Spring in general, so I'm definitely not set in my ways. Any suggestions of how to do this better / different will be considered.

Thanks all!

Comment: are you using hibernateTemplate or jdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously there is more than a dozen ways of doing this, Easiest way of doing this using @Value autowiring..

```
@Value("#{findQueries.queryKey}")
String query;
```

One other way of doing is to autowire the properties and then lookup for the key...

Comment: +1 a good example of how keeping it simple leads to elegant code.

Comment: this is interesting, and i have never seen that syntax before. i do have one other problem, however. i have numbered parameters i need to pass in to the property.

Comment: numbered parameters? Please explain

Comment: You can check out https://github.com/chrislovecnm/Blog-Projects and my blog http://chrislovecnm.com for some examples of what Teja is recommending.

Comment: what i mean by numbered parameters is in the query i have things like "My dog is {0}". how do i pass in the {0} part?

Answer (score 1):

You can hook up your properties object for where you need it, by injecting it (for example into your controller class):

```
@Autowired()
@Qualifier("findQueries")
private Properties findQueries;

private void setFindQueries(Properties findQueries) {
    this.findQueries = findQueries;
}

public void someotherMethod() {
    findQueries.getProperty(...)
}
```